# general form sin and arctan integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Show that:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan(x/2)}{\tan(a/2)}\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{2n}\left[(-1)^{n+1}+\left(\sec(a)-\tan(a)\right)^{n}\right]$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you see an arctangent in an integral...integrate by parts!  The integral is then

$$\frac1{n}\left [-\cos{n x} \arctan{\left (\frac{\tan{\frac{x}{2}}}{\tan{\frac{a}{2}}} \right )}  \right ]_0^{\pi} +\frac{\tan{\frac{a}{2}}}{2 n} \int_0^{\pi} dx \, \cos{n x} \frac{\sec^2{\frac{x}{2}}}{\tan^2{\frac{a}{2}}+\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}}$$

The integral on the right may be simplified to

$$\cos^2{\frac{a}{2}} \int_0^{2 \pi} dx \frac{\cos{n x}}{1-\cos{a} \cos{x}}$$

We may use the residue theorem here by making the sub $z=e^{i x}$; consider the real part of the integral

$$i 2 \cos^2{\frac{a}{2}} \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{z^n}{(\cos{a})\, z^2-2 z+\cos{a}}$$

We assume $a\in [0,\pi]$.  The only pole inside the unit circle is $z_- = (1-\sin{a})/\cos{a}$.  The integral is simply $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at that pole, or

$$(i 2 \pi) i \cos^2{\frac{a}{2}} \frac{(1-\sin{a})^n/\cos^n{a}}{-\sin{a}}  = \frac{\pi}{\tan{\frac{a}{2}}} (\sec{a}-\tan{a})^n$$

Therefore I get, for the integral,

$$\frac{\pi}{2 n} \left [(-1)^{n+1}+(\sec{a}-\tan{a})^n \right ]$$

Comment: I posted this integral for fun in case anyone found it interesting or worth doing. That's all.   That minus sign is a typo. Sorry. I will fix it.

Comment: @Cody: it was fun.  Thanks.  Also worth doing: we just found the coefficients of the Fourier series for a very complicated-looking function.

Comment: sounds interesting. Wow!.  Oh, you're referring to this problem?. Actually, I tackled this one the same way you just did. A few different, but equivalent trig functions. I felt good when I saw the padowan had emulated the master :)